# How to copy random generated numbers to the selection sort method. (JAVA)

Tags: java, sorting

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


public class Sorting
{
   public static int numOfComps = 0,
                     numOfSwaps = 0;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        System.out.println("\nOriginal order:");
        int size = 5;

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);


        for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        {
           list.add(i);
        }

        Random rand = new Random();
        while(list.size() > 0)
        {
         int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
         System.out.print(list.remove(index) + " ");
        }

      System.out.println();

       int[] test = convertIntegers(list);
       int[] a = new int[5];

       // Selection Sort
       System.out.println("\n\nSelection Sort");

       // Display copy of random generated number original order
       System.out.println("\nOriginal order:");      
       System.arraycopy(test, 0, a, 0, test.length);
       System.out.println(a + " ");

       // Selection Sort method
       selectionSort(a);

       System.out.println("\nSorted order: ");
       for(int element : a)
         System.out.print(element + " ");
    }

    public static int[] convertIntegers(ArrayList<Integer> integers)
    {
        int[] num = new int[integers.size()];
        for (int i=0; i < num.length; i++)
        {
        num[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
        }
        return num;
     }

   public static void selectionSort(int[] array)
   {
      int startScan;   // Starting position of the scan
      int index;       // To hold a subscript value
      int minIndex;    // Element with smallest value in the scan
      int minValue;    // The smallest value found in the scan

      // The outer loop iterates once for each element in the
      // array. The startScan variable marks the position where
      // the scan should begin.
      for (startScan = 0; startScan < (array.length-1); startScan++)
      {
         // Assume the first element in the scannable area
         // is the smallest value.
         minIndex = startScan;
         minValue = array[startScan];

         // Scan the array, starting at the 2nd element in
         // the scannable area. We are looking for the smallest
         // value in the scannable area. 
         for(index = startScan + 1; index < array.length; index++)
         {
            if (array[index] < minValue)
            {
               minValue = array[index];
               minIndex = index;
            }

            // Counts the number of values comparisons
            numOfComps ++;
         }
         // Counts the number of values swaps
         if(minIndex != startScan)
            {
                numOfSwaps ++;
            }

         // Swap the element with the smallest value 
         // with the first element in the scannable area.
         array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
         array[startScan] = minValue;

      }
       System.out.println("\nNumber of comps = " + numOfComps);
       System.out.println("Number of swaps = " + numOfSwaps);
    }
}
```

How do I write code to copy random generated numbers to the selection sort method so that the random generated numbers can be displayed as an exact copy under the displayed heading "Selection Sort" as well as displaying the number of comparisons and swaps, and the sorted order? The code I have provided is not working properly. Thank you for any help.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, why don't you apply random inside for loop while inserting the elements itself? rather than `list.add(i);` add the `rand.nextInt(list.size);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
 //generate random number here and assign to arr[i]
}
enter code here
```

now add another for loop to display everything inside the array, then if you want to see if it works sort it then use another loop.

Comment: @JRichardSnape Hi Richard, I could really use your help again, you helped me tremendously before. I've tried to implement the code provided by the 2 programmers who responded to my question but I'm very green at programming; I have less than a year of exposure to programming. If you would, please show me how you would code this program to get it to work the way I need it to. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Catchwa Hi Catchwa, I'm using your ArrayList<Integer> random number generator, but having trouble getting the random numbers to copy to the Selection sort method. How do I get the random numbers to copy to the sort method? Thanks.

Comment: You can call the sort method and pass it the array you could have a class variable and make it static that might be what you looking for also if you find this helps you can make my answer the preferred one.

Comment: Hi Thorx99, your code worked great; I just had to get the rest of the code from another source. How do I make your answer the preferred one? Thanks for all your help! :-)

Okay, I clicked on the "check mark" and it turned green. Does that make your answer the preferred one?